# WiFi fails to resume from suspend, only if suspending using GUI

Tags: wireless, suspend, dell, atheros

I have a Dell XPS 13 9360 with a Qualcomm Killer Wifi Card. I have been having problems with wifi and bluetooth being unavailable after resume from suspend since I installed 18.04. The problem was intermittent, sometimes it failed to start after resume, sometimes it worked fine.

Looking for the reason I realized that only when suspending using the gui, or if suspend was due to inactive time, WiFi failed to start on resume. but if I suspended closing the lid of the laptop, WiFi worked fine when resuming.

What is the difference between suspending one way or another? Is there anything I could try to solve the WiFi resume problems? (other than always suspending closing the lid)

Comment: First try `systemctl suspend` from the command line and see if that method has the desired result.

Comment: Perhaps your wifi-card gets blocked by software, or some hardware-button? Just run `rfkill list` to check this, when the problem occurs.